# USB mouse does not work

Tags: usb, lubuntu, mouse

I have installed lubuntu 14.04 both on my desktop computer and on my laptop.
On my desktop computer, I have an old ball type ps2 mouse, which now starts to fail (cable problems).
My optical usb mouse which works perfectly on my laptop, will not work on my desktop computer; I tried all different usb ports , tried pluggin in before and after boot .. the light is on, the mouse does not work.
Any idea?

Comment: What is the output of `lsusb` and (trimmed output of) `dmesg` before and after plugging in your mouse?

Comment: Output of lsusb:

Comment: would like to add the outputs to my question, but can't find the "edit" butten to edit my question. Outputs are to big for comments ..

Answer (score -1):

you need to try other usb device at first as flash usb or any other , if they also stopped so you need to check your BIOS option to active usb control

start your computer and press Delete key when you see the first black screen then (if you have other option to open bios do it) then choose > integrated peripherals , go to usb controller by keys up down and press enter then make it enabled press enter and save your BIOS f10 , it will work [image: see this picture]

Comment: Other usb divices, as external HDD, printer, or scanner wor without problems.

Comment: if you have the option of usb mouse support in BIOS option enable it, also use option of ubuntu , click option icon and choose mouse (or type mouse in the search and choose it) connect your usb mouse and choose test your settings , but i think it's bios problem because the ps2 work normal, or the usb mouse need to new other one.

Comment: In BIOS, one USB controller was disabled; enabling did't bring any change, however. No option for USB mouse in BIOS.
Mouse preferences in lubuntu only offer to adjust mouse speed and lft/right hand adjustment.
I have had a USB mouse working with my desktop pc before; this one is broken (doesn't work on my laptop either). The new one works with the laptop but not with the desktop pc.
Is there a possibility to activate usb mouse control via terminal?

Comment: okay I want you to try new other mouse maybe the problem with it

Comment: will buy new other usb mouse soon and try .. - thanks so far!